# How many data nodes do we need as a function of shards and indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

How many data nodes do we need in a cluster as a function of total number of indexes and shards per index to ensure that if a node goes down a primary and replicate shard isn't on the same node.

Note, in out cluster all the indexes contain similar data and all indexes have the same sharding number

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Primary and Replica shards are NEVER allocated on the same node. So, if you have 2 nodes and one of them goes down all the shards on that node will be unassigned and any replica shards on the other healthy node will be promoted to become primary shards.

So, if your index has replica shards configured then the minimum required nodes is 2. However, depending on your data size and usage you will need to size your ES cluster with appropriate number of nodes.